# How to delete an element using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do delete a selected element from the list of elements on click a delete button using bootstrap of Javascript. I am using checkbox to select an element

Comment: `element.parentNode.removeChild(element)`

Comment: kindly show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X73vB/16/) it will help you. it remove selected `rows` of `table`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I want to deleted an element that is checked using delete button like we delete a mail from inbox in gmail

Comment: I have to first select the element using checkbox and onclick a delete button, the selected element should be deleted

Answer (score 0):

First, find the `index` of the element you want to remove:

```
var array = [2, 5, 9];
var index = array.indexOf(5);
```

Then remove it with `splice`:

```
if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

The second parameter of splice is the number of elements to remove. Note that splice modifies the array in place and returns a new array containing the elements that have been removed.